# jquery script does not work after linking a document using include in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a laravel blade document which calls another laravel document and then it should perform a series of functions in javascript, the problem is that that jquery code does not work for me, I leave the code here, thanks in advance.

**Html 1 Document name "crear-albaran-entrada" (workinf perfect)**

```
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('content_header')

   <h1>Crear albarán entrada </h1>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/albaranE.css') }}" >

@endsection

@section('content')

<input id="#precio-1" type="text">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(#precio-1).css('background','red');
</script>

@endsection
```

**Html 2 Document name "crear-albaran-salida" (Problem with read jQuery)**

```
   @extends('adminlte::page')

@section('content_header')
    <h1>Crear albarán salida </h1>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/albaranE.css') }}" >
    
  
@endsection

@section('content')

@include('albaranes.crear-albaran-entrada')
  @stack('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('ready'); // not working
            $("#precio-1").css("border","1px solid red "); // not working
    </script>   
  @endstack

@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@stack` to output a stack of content on a specific position in your template.

To add items to this stack, you can use `@push` and `@prepend`.

So, you've got them mixed up and should be using `@push` here instead of `@stack`.

For further details, look at the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#stacks

Comment: Can you post the rendered html output of the page?

Comment: I'm sorry, the translator I use is a bit bad, you label them push and prepend, I used them previously without result and the problem is that it does not show an error in the console

Answer (score -1):

Working friends mi code html 2:

```
    @include('albaranes.crear-albaran-entrada')

    <script type="text/javascript">
           
            $("#label_proveedor").text("Cliente");
         
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you mean to edit your original post or is this yor working solution? Looks like you tried to edit

Comment: this mi solution mi friend